# Android Assign LiveData<> to ListView

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a list view to display Users and an Adapter that works well together on normal ArrayLists of Users 
However i'm trying to implement ViewModels and cannot get my ListView adapter to work with LiveData. I cant get any of the similar questions/answers to work for me.
But this feels fairly fundamental and like it should be easy.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MainActivityViewModel mainActivityViewModel;
ListView usersLV;
UsersAdapter userAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    usersLV = findViewById(R.id.usersLV);

    ArrayList<User> users = (ArrayList<User>)mainActivityViewModel.getUsers().getValue();
    if (users != null){
        userAdapter = new UsersAdapter(this,users);
        usersLV.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    }else{
        Log.d("gwyd","user list was null");
        userAdapter = new UsersAdapter(this,new ArrayList<User>());
        usersLV.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    }


    mainActivityViewModel.getUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<User> users) {
            if(users != null) {
                userAdapter.setUsers(users);
            }else {
                Log.d("gwyd","no users found in db");
                userAdapter.setUsers(new ArrayList<User>());
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private DaoRepository daoRepository;
private LiveData<List<User>> users;


public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
    if (users == null){
        updateUsersList();
    }
    return users;
}
public MainActivityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    daoRepository = new DaoRepository(application);
    users = updateUsersList();
}
public LiveData<List<User>> updateUsersList(){
    return daoRepository.getAllUsers();
}}
```

and UserAdapter:

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
private List<User> users;

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public UsersAdapter(Context context, List<User> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    User user = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userLvItemTV);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvName.setText(user.getUserName());
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}}
```

And the List_item Layout file

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userLvItemTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having some stern words with myself I've come up with this as the solution: 
Basically the same as what i was doing but in your observers onChange method use getApplicationContext() instead of 'this' to initialize the ArrayAdapter. It seems the activities context cant be accessed from the observers inner class and throws a vague error that led to the confusion...

I need to read up more on how the different contexts affect things. but if no-one comes up with a slam dunk this is how to do it i'll probably mark this as the answer in a couple days because it seems to have fixed the problem.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MainActivityViewModel mainActivityViewModel;
ListView usersLV;
UsersAdapter userAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    usersLV = findViewById(R.id.usersLV);

    mainActivityViewModel.getUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<User> users) {
            if(users != null) {
                userAdapter =new UsersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), users);
                usersLV.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }
            userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}}
```

View Model:

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private DaoRepository daoRepository;
private LiveData<List<User>> users;


public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
    if (users == null){
       users = updateUsersList();
    }
    return users;
}
public MainActivityViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    daoRepository = new DaoRepository(application);
    users = updateUsersList();
}
public LiveData<List<User>> updateUsersList(){
    return daoRepository.getAllUsers();
}}
```

ArrayAdapter:

```
public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

public UsersAdapter(Context context, List<User> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    User user = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userLvItemTV);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvName.setText(user.getUserName());
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}

List Item Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userLvItemTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But now you're recreating an adapter everytime your list of users changes. That doesn't seem right. Almyk's answer below looks more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
mainActivityViewModel.getUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<User> users) {
            playerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

To:

```
mainActivityViewModel.getUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<User> users) {
            playerAdapter.setUsers(users);
        }
    });
```

And in your adapter create a setter such as:

```
public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: My getUsers method is returning null somehow, so i'm going to have to look into that a bit. But this makes sense. give the array adapter a reference to the list of users

Comment: I've made your suggested changes, iv'e had to add some other changes too to stop it from crashing,  mostly checking for null returns.   Its now at the point where when i'ts making the adapter it cannot find any users so uses the else part of the statment. Then when onChange gets hit it can find the user in the list but still isn't outputting him as expected.

Comment: (ArrayList<User>)mainActivityViewModel.getUsers().getValue()   Seems to always return null unless it's in the onChange... but then i cant set it to the adapter in there and get this  error:  (UsersAdapter
(android.content.Context,
List<User>)
in UsersAdapter cannot be applied
to
(anonymous android.arch.lifecycle.Observer<java.util.List<com.example.coursework.model.User>>,
List<User>)
 )    Also we've given the Adapter a list of users but not stated how to get it to use that list and not it's original one/set the original list to this one.  Baffled

Comment: I think your problem lies in here:

```public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
    if (users == null){
        updateUsersList();
    }
    return users;```


change so that:
```users = updateUsersList();```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Live Data directly in the Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mCtx;
    private final LiveData<List<MyModel>> mLiveDate;

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, LiveData<List<MyModel>> livedata) {
        mCtx = ctx;
        mLiveDate= livedata;
        livedata.observeForever(myModels -> notifyDataSetChanged());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mLiveDate.getValue() == null)
            return 0;
        return mLiveDate.getValue().size();
    }

    @Override
    public MyModel getItem(int i) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(mLiveDate.getValue()).get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ...

        MyModel data = getItem(i);

    ...
        return view;
    }
```